# How to find other built-in DWT fields?

Tags: tridion

Within a DWT Template Building Block, we can use a few "free" variables such as `@@Component.Title@@` or `@@Component.ID@@` as well as [built-in DWT functions](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/BuiltInFunctionsForUseInHtmlTemplates).

I didn't realize we can also get a component's *schema* description with `@@Component.Description@@` or `@@Description@@`.

The out-of-the-box `Default Dreamweaver Component Design` has a good set of examples, along with the [Tridion Cook book's iteration example](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/IteratingOverMultivalueEmbeddedFields), and [SDL Live Content](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/idheading-158523168).

**How else could I find other allowed built-in DWT functions and variables, programmatic or otherwise?**

*In other words, I wouldn't have thought `@@Description@@` was even available in DWT without seeing an example first (not that I have a use for it yet).*

**Edit** (June 8, 2013): I did find additional information on SDL Live Content ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)). We can of course use available [Package variables as described in the documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_915DDB8970C14E2A91AC0DC1B00BEA79).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Researching a bit, I found that if we go to the tridion.contenmanager.config file, we will discover the  node, which references to the Dreamweaver mediator type:

```xml
<mediator matchMIMEType="text/x-tcm-dreamweaver" type="Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Dreamweaver.DreamweaverMediator" />
```

This namespace can be found inside `Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.dll`

Decompiling is the best way to find out what is inside and learn something. Since it is .Net code, that will not be a problem, there is many free good tools available. I'm using lately **JustDecompile**

I did not go too deep into the code, but I can see that there is a `TridionObjectSource` class, with a number of Constants for reserved words, like:

- `ReservedNameTitle`
- `ReservedNameDescription`

Searching where this constants are used on the code, can help to better understand what they do, and the way the Dreamweaver Mediator works inside.

Seems like an interesting learning exercise

Comment: Accurate answer, but please be cautious de-compiling DLLs when most license agreements with SDL Tridion explicitly forbid this. I am sure they won't care in this case, but posting the de-compiled code will likely be extra frowned upon.

Comment: +1, since I did ask about *programmatic* ways to understand the possible functions. I also second Chris's point, but understand where to find what's _possible_, though not necessarily what's _supported_.

Answer (score 2):

I take it that you've searched the documentation for the answer and come up empty. I suggest that you go to the relevant part of the LiveContent documentation and add a comment. This will reach the documentation team directly, and I'm sure they'll be very interested to hear of a feature that isn't properly covered. With a bit of luck they'll update it, and you'll have done us all a favour.

I have some sympathy for the "help yourself" approach too, but if you find a feature by your own analysis of the software, and it gets removed in a later release, you won't have a leg to stand on to complain about this. So help Tridion to get the feature documented, and then it's there to use with confidence.

Comment: +1, and good point--[I posted it](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/idheading-359684656).